# How to install only dependencies in package.json when deploy a GCP cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want install only `dependencies` in `package.json` without installing `devDependencies` when use `gcloud beta functions deploy xxx` command to deploy a cloud function.

`runtime: nodejs6`

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming you are saying that if your package.json contains a devDependencies section then when you perform a gcloud functions deploy, the packages mentioned in devDependencies are also being installed.  I think we should consider the package.json as a root level package and hence the semantics are correct.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies

Comment: Please edit your question to add more detail.  Are you targeting node 6 or 8?